# How to authorized user with Active Directory and Asp.net Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-web-api2

i managed to authenticate a user through Active Directory with this code

```
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ADPath, domainAndUsername, password);
            object obj = entry.NativeObject;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (null == result)
            {
                return "false";
            }
```

after if user is authenticated i want to create authorization rule for this user to block access to ApiControllers that i have

how can i do that ?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: implement a custom owin external authenticator that will enable authorization once login details is valid :)

Comment: i have a really big mess with all authentication methods .. 
i just want to create a cookie and Authorized rule for api controller to block access and cant make it work

Comment: just use owin or asp identity no need to create a custom one

Comment: i managed to create a Bearer token and to get data from controller with
[Authorize] attribute .. but now i want to create roles for  [Authorize]
how can i do that ?

Comment: Just mix owin with asp identity if you want roles :)